# Proper approach for calculating vertex-level clustering

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to calculate the clustering of each vertex in my graph, where clustering is defined at the vertex level as being the percentage of possible inter-neighbor links actually formed (e.g., if vertex i has 4 neighbors, there are six possible links between the neighbors).

I'm just starting to learn some more formal things about networks, but it seems this should be a pretty common operation/measure of "tightness" of a network.

However, I couldn't find a canned function for calculating this with `igraph`. The `clusters` and `cluster.distribution` functions both seem to be dealing with what I would call "components", and from what I can tell these are both simply aliases for `components` and `component.distribution`, respectively.

For example, for `g = make_graph("Bull")`, the clustering by vertex is:

```
v |  c
-------
1 |  1
2 | 1/3
3 | 1/3
4 | 0 [by convention]
5 | 0 [by convention]
```

I could get this with the following

```
library(igraph)
g = make_graph("Bull")
sapply(adjacent_vertices(g, seq_len(vcount(g))), 
       function(x) {
         neigh = as.vector(x)
         if (length(neigh) <= 1L) return(0)
         sum(g[neigh, neigh])/
           (length(neigh)^2 - length(neigh))})
# [1] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

But this seems verbose and likely inefficient.

Is there a more canonical way to do this with `igraph`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) captures this. In `igraph`, the call is `transitivity`. Use `"local"` for the `type` argument. You can also specify if you want `0`s or `NA`s for the isolates:

```
library(igraph)
g = make_graph("Bull")
transitivity(g, type="local")
# [1] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333       NaN       NaN
transitivity(g, type="local", isolates = "zero")
# [1] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000
```